# Selection of atleast one object and at most $r$ objects from $(2r+1)$ distinct objects.

Tags: combinatorics

The total number of ways of selecting at least one object and at most $r$ objects from $(2r+1)$ distinct objects is $255$ , find $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, note that $255$ is one less than that of the number of selections of at most $r$ objects from $2r+1$ distinct objects. (Can you see why?) This is half of the number of selections from $2r+1$ distinct objects. (Can you see why?) Thus, there are $512$ selections from $2r+1$ distinct objects. (Can you see why?)

What is the total number of possible selections from $n$ distinct objects *in general*? What can you conclude about $r$?